# Moving 3d Object in three JS by BUTTON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm a beginner at Three JS and need some help with my code. Please, Could you help me for a second?

1| Button1 **"increase + 1"**. After Clicking **Button 1, ROOM1** will move to **ROOM2** Location and so forth. **Room8** will move to **ROOM1** position.

2| Button2 **"increase + 2"**. After Clicking **Button 2, ROOM1** will move to **ROOM3** Location and so forth. **Room8** will move to **ROOM2** position.

Here's an example of what I mean: [image]

This is my Code in Sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-code-3rlk8b?file=/src/components/PartOne.js

Please help me.

Thank You So much for Your Precious Time

I'm expecting the solution that how can I use a click button and move my 3d Objects(room)

Comment: If this were just three nodes, like your question here, it's a simple matter of a circular linked list.  But your sandbox shows eight nodes, so it's impossible to know which nodes are leaves and how they should rearrange.  TL;DR: What happens to the inside nodes?

Comment: Actually, there are 8 nodes/rooms. In the picture I just show an example

Comment: See the answer by @Arjun.  I think he's on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using react state changes i did this solution.

First, you have positioned every room at a fixed point. You need to rotate the rooms which means you need to change their positions.

For this, i changed the fixed points in Room components to take it from props.

Example: for room8,

```
export function Room8({position,...props}) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('./models/room8.glb')
  return (
    <group castShadow receiveShadow {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group castShadow receiveShadow position={position} rotation={[Math.PI, 0, Math.PI]}>
    ...your code
    </group>
  </group>
  )
}
```

do this for all rooms.

Then add those positions as array in your `PartOne.js`

```
const positions= useMemo(()=>[
    [0,0,0],
    [-4, -2.7, 0],
    [-0.5, -2.7, 3.6],
    [-7.6, -5.5, 0],
    [-4.5, -5.5, 3.6],
    [-0.4, -5.5, 7.2],
    [-7.6, -8.3, 3.55],
    [-4, -8.3, 7.2]
]);
```

In `PartOne.js`

add a state to have your rooms in order.

```
const [rooms,setRooms]=useState(
    [RoomOne,Room2,Room3,Room4,Room5,Room6,Room7,Room8]
);
```

add your button and rotate the room array,

```
<button onClick={()=>{
   let arr=[...rooms];
   arr.unshift(arr.pop())
   console.log("arr::",arr)
   setRooms(arr)
}}>Rotate +1</button>
```

render the state `rooms` inside canvas,

```
<Canvas shadows camera={{ fov:70, position: [0,0,30] }} >
    <Suspense fallback={null}  >
       <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
       <directionalLight castShadow receiveShadow intensity={2} position={[80,80,80]} />
     {rooms.map((room,roomIndex)=>room({position:positions[roomIndex]}))}
       <ContactShadows />
    </Suspense>
    <OrbitControls enablePan={true} enableZoom={true} enableRotate={true} />
 </Canvas>
```

Adding the sandbox with above changes for your reference,

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-code-forked-nhpubx?file=/src/components/PartOne.js)

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. But when I used the button to change their position I got an unwanted gap between these rooms. Can you please check that?